# can't launch vscode in docker container errno = Operation not permitted

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code

I have a docker container where I installed the vscode at first it's worked fin no problems but once I have updated the vscode (from 1.55.1 to 1.60.1) I stack in this error, I don't know if it's duplicated or not but I couldn't find any solution except this one:

```
$>> sudo code --user-data-dir="/path/to/folder/to/use" --no-sandbox
```

it's working but as root not a good solution if there's another way please help,

the error message;

```
$>> code --verbose
Failed to move to new namespace: PID namespaces supported, Network namespace supported, but failed: errno = Operation not permitted
```

Comment: maybe this will help you https://github.com/jessfraz/dockerfiles/issues/65#issuecomment-266532289

Comment: not working the `sysctl kernel.unprivileged_userns_clone=1` already done and can not be changed `read only file` also I have done what it's suggested in the post but nothing still the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried so many solution none works so I just remove it and installed the old version ([old version 1.55](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_55))